# ActAsList Gem not saving order correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, list, sorting

I'm using the [Acts As List](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) Gem. I have a table which I'm trying to dynamically reorder by dragging the rows up/down then saving that position to the database.

At the moment if I drag and drop a row then refresh the page, it always puts that row at the top regardless of where it's been dragged to:

models/border.rb

```
acts_as_list :column => :position
```

controllers/borders_controller.rb

```
def sort
  @border = Border.find(params[:id])
  @border.insert_at(params[:position].to_i+1)
  render nothing: true
end
```

views/index.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" id="sortable" data-update_url="<%= sort_admin_borders_path%>">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:10px !important;">Position</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Colour</th>
    <th>Texture</th>
    <th>Pattern</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @borders.each do |border| %>
  <tr data-item_id="<%=border.id%>" class='draggable-item' style="cursor: row-resize;">
    <td><%= border.position %></td>
    <td><%= link_to border.name, admin_border_path(border) %></td>
    <td style="background: <%= border.colour %> "></td>
    <td><%= border.texture %></td>
    <td><%= border.pattern %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Delete", admin_border_path(border), method: :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this border?" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

<% if @borders.empty? %>
  <tr class="warning"><td colspan="5"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> No borders found</td></tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

Console when I move a row:

`**Started POST "/admin/borders/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 10:50:34 +0100
Processing by Admin::BordersController#sort as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"10", "display_order_position"=>"3"}
  Admin Load (16.5ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = 23 LIMIT 1
  Border Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "components".* FROM "components" WHERE "components"."type" IN ('Border') AND "components"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "10"]]
  SQL (7.8ms)  UPDATE "components" SET position = (position + 1) WHERE "components"."type" IN ('Border') AND (1 = 1 AND position >= 1 AND position < 2)
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
   (1.6ms)  UPDATE "components" SET "position" = 1, "updated_at" = '2014-08-12 09:50:34.400216' WHERE "components"."type" IN ('Border') AND "components"."id" = 10
   (1.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "components" WHERE "components"."type" IN ('Border') AND (1 = 1 AND position = 1)
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)**`

Comment: Could you show your javascript responsible for calling sort please? If it fails to send position param, than everything is clear.

Comment: I've updated with the whole table and also what the console shows when I drag a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the form is sending `params[:display_order_position]` (seen in your log) and you're using `params[:position]` in the controller.  `params[:position]` will be `nil`, and acts_as_list will call `to_i` on this, and `nil.to_i` comes out as 0, so it's as if you're trying to set the position to 0 every time.

You need to either change your javascript to send `params[:position]` or change your controller code to use `params[:display_order_position]`.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure I'm not referencing `:display_order_position` anywhere?

Comment: It's impossible to say unless you post the javascript that's calling the sort action, as @BroiSatse asked for already.